# Redirecting WMTS traffic from logged in browser session to QGIS

Tags: qgis, wmts

I have access to a WMTS behind a website login in my browser but would like to gain access to it in QGIS. I've tried adding the WMTS link that I could find from a tile using the developer tools but it doesn't work and I keep getting the error message "Failed to download capabilities". I've tried basic authentication with the account I use in the browser and also played with all of the other settings in QGIS I could find but without success.

Is there any way that I could redirect the WMTS traffic from my browser session to QGIS?

Comment: when you say you've tried adding the WMTS link, does that link give you a GetCapabilities response in your browser?

Comment: What is the link?